# learning UART with HM-10, FTDI 232r 3v3 usb cable and iOS dabble app

Tags: serial-port, bluetooth-lowenergy, uart

I am learning UART communication via Dabble iOS app, HM-10 and an FTDI 232r 3v3 cable. Thinking of using the dabble app to control a robotic car with an arduino nano and HM-10 ble. I have the following hardware:

- HM-10 (according to this page, https://www.martyncurrey.com/hm-10-bluetooth-4ble-modules/, I have the HM-10S-B). Should be 3.3v logic
- FTDI 232r 3v3 USB cable. This cable is 3.3v logic

When I use the dabble app and I send text to the HM-10 via the 'terminal' functionality I get legible results as you can see in the first image. There is some packet padding but I get the expected results. In this case I sent 'Test', then 'A', then 'B' and then 'c'.
[image]

When I switch to the 'gamepad' feature and I click on the up/right/down/left/square/etc buttons the results appear to be the same no matter what I press (see second image). Here I pressed up, right, down, left, square, cirle in that order.

[image] Perhaps the baud rate of the gamepad feature is different. I've tried changing the serial monitor speed and other settings to no avail. I've tried other apps and in most cases the terminal features work but the gamepads do not. I'm trying to figure out what is going on here and want to know how to diagnose/reverse engineer. I'm not sure why they would send vastly different data or something that is not legible in the serial monitor. I understand that if you pressed the 'left' button, perhaps the message was to 'turn left, keep turning left and then keep going forward'. Still, to me it seems that the message sent after pressing 'left' could simply be an 'L' or maybe something more but not this ineligible set of characters.
I've said enough. Anything to help understand/track down where my thinking is off would be greatly appreciated.

p.s. I tried reading the serial communication with an arduino nano and hardware/software serial and the results were the same. Terminal text arrived as expected. Gamepad communication was a bunch of squares and other special characters that I'm not sure make sense...

Comment: Treating unknown data as ASCII text is foolish. You need to examine unknown data in its raw form, i.e. as numbers, rather than decoded characters.

Comment: Understood. When sending movement information to a robot why would you want to send non text data? For example, if I want to turn right, I can send any number of raw data, etc., including the character 'r'. Then the code in the robot can interpret that as, turn right 30 degrees and stop or turn 90 degrees and keep going forward. I see that in joystick mode you would send different gradations of movements. But for up(fwd)/down(backward)/left/right I could see it either way. 
Are there any phone apps that hobbyists like to use for controlling robots; ones with good documentation and examples?

Comment: "*why would you want to send non text data?*" - Because when data is transmitted, it can be corrupted. A message protocol that contains additional data for message validation will be more reliable than a single letter command. Also, when you need to send more information than a single letter command (i.e. something other than a trivial example and/or there's no human in a feedback loop), when using text instead of binary you risk wasting bandwidth and using more processing on reception & decoding. Text is for the benefit of humans; computers are more efficient with binary data than text.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. While looking into this issue I transitioned to using VS Code & PlatformIO which is quite nice. While outputting the data I did see the STX and SOH characters along side a single or multiple characters for example. I also saw that a gamepad key press sends the first packet with the key identifier and also another 2nd packet (not sure precisely why). At this point I'm getting the hang of it but now working on dealing with variable size packets and variable number of packets. Any good resources on that topic (handling serial comm) would be most appreciated!